# How can I make this JavaScript interval random?

Tags: javascript

How do I make this interval from every 2 seconds to randomly X - X seconds? Also, how do I change the increment from every 2 increments as well to randomly X - X? If you see a flaw in my code or improvement needed please as well let me know, in separate code if willing. Much appreciated.

```
<div id="counter"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var START_DATE = new Date("January 1, 2012 12:00:00"); // put in the starting date here
  var INTERVAL    = 2; // in seconds
  var INCREMENT   = 2; // increase per tick
  var START_VALUE = 5000; // initial value when it's the start date
  var count = 0;
  window.onload = function()
  {
    var msInterval = INTERVAL * 2000;
    var now = new Date();
    count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;
    setInterval(
      "count += INCREMENT; document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;", msInterval);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It sounds as though you're just needing a random number for msInterval?

Comment: `Have you researched [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)?

Comment: Zounds of Math.random mentioning answers incoming. )) But in truth, the invervals most certainly _will be_ random.

Comment: Also ick don't pass strings to `setInterval()`.

Comment: I need an answer to my question so if any one can help me that would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Pointy I'd say "don't use setInterval at all", but that's just me. )

Comment: @raina77ow agreed, though if done properly it does work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To generate a number between 2 and 5 use

> var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*3+2;

- If it rolls a 0 you get 2, if it rolls a 3 you get 5.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var START_DATE = new Date("January 1, 2012 12:00:00"); // put in the starting date here
  var INTERVAL    = 2;
  var INCREMENT   = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+2;
  var START_VALUE = 5000; // initial value when it's the start date
  var count = 0;
  window.onload = function()
  {
    var msInterval = INTERVAL * 2000;
    var now = new Date();
    count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;
    setInterval(
      "count += INCREMENT; document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;",     msInterval);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: yes but perhaps I need it to be exactly 2 seconds to 5 seconds?

Comment: Then do some math, @ZachReynolds...  pretty simple to take a random number of 0 - 100 and convert that to an equally-random number.

Comment: @ZachReynolds  I don't want to start anything flame-y, but dude, c'mon, you can't use that example to figure out how to get a range from 2-5 seconds??

Comment: can you please show me a full mark up of the code how it should be with random?

Comment: the increments are not random =/

Comment: Thought the interval was random, it's fixed.

Comment: the time it updates is not random I meant, it still does not seem to be random incrementally either

Comment: On seperate instances the interval and increment have been set to random, you're failing to explain your problem adequately. With the provided code in any of these answers you should be more than capable of applying it to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Random number between two numbers

```
var min = 1000, max = 10000;
var msInterval = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```

use a closure in setInterval dont pass as string

```
setInterval(function(){
    count += INCREMENT; 
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;
    }, msInterval);
```

fiddle fiddle, I edited some big values to make it faster http://jsfiddle.net/sabithpocker/8CpaF/

Comment: closures tutorial : http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.closures

Comment: The random interval and increment still is not random, the 5 in > "min = 2, max = 5;" is only what is "random" nothing more nothing less. I am not sure why it does not do random.